# using mongodb case insentive regex with case insentive index

Tags: regex, mongodb, performance

is mongo regex ignoring my index? I have a case insentive index, but by the look of things my regex search recognize it and ignores it.

```
db.getCollection("myCol").find({ value: /^mysearchVal/i }}).explain(...)
```

I have 95, 708 docs total.

output:

```
{
  "queryPlanner": {
    "plannerVersion": 1,
    "namespace": "myDb.myCol",
    "indexFilterSet": false,
    "parsedQuery": {
        "Value": {
            "$regex": "^mysearchVal",
            "$options": "i"
        }
    },
    "winningPlan": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "filter": {
            "Value": {
                "$regex": "^mysearchVal",
                "$options": "i"
            }
        },
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern": {
                "Value": 1
            },
            "indexName": "value_case_insensitive_and_unique",
            "collation": {
                "locale": "en",
                "caseLevel": false,
                "caseFirst": "off",
                "strength": 2,
                "numericOrdering": false,
                "alternate": "non-ignorable",
                "maxVariable": "punct",
                "normalization": false,
                "backwards": false,
                "version": "57.1"
            },
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
                "Value": []
            },
            "isUnique": true,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
                "Value": [
                    "[\"\", {})",
                    "[/^mysearchVal/i, /^mysearchVal/i]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans": []
},
"executionStats": {
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 1,
    "executionTimeMillis": 1447,
    "totalKeysExamined": 95708,
    "totalDocsExamined": 95708,
    "executionStages": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "filter": {
            "Value": {
                "$regex": "^mysearchVal",
                "$options": "i"
            }
        },
        "nReturned": 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1270,
        "works": 95709,
        "advanced": 1,
        "needTime": 95707,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 785,
        "restoreState": 785,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "invalidates": 0,
        "docsExamined": 95708,
        "alreadyHasObj": 0,
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned": 95708,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 596,
            "works": 95709,
            "advanced": 95708,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 785,
            "restoreState": 785,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "invalidates": 0,
            "keyPattern": {
                "Value": 1
            },
            "indexName": "value_case_insensitive_and_unique",
            "collation": {
                "locale": "en",
                "caseLevel": false,
                "caseFirst": "off",
                "strength": 2,
                "numericOrdering": false,
                "alternate": "non-ignorable",
                "maxVariable": "punct",
                "normalization": false,
                "backwards": false,
                "version": "57.1"
            },
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
                "Value": []
            },
            "isUnique": true,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
                "Value": [
                    "[\"\", {})",
                    "[/^mysearchVal/i, /^mysearchVal/i]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined": 95708,
            "seeks": 1,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "dupsDropped": 0,
            "seenInvalidated": 0
        }
    },
    "allPlansExecution": []
  },
  "ok": 1.0
}
```

the output shows 95,708 keys and docs examined, 1 doc returned. really? did the index apply in this case or am I missing a point or two?

Answer (score 0):

> Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use
>   indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware
>   and is unable to utilize case-insensitive indexes.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use